# React: Failed to compile; index.js

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, compiler-errors

So I decided to learn React and on the very first project I got an error message.

**Failed to compile**

> ./src/index.js
>
> Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App').

It's simple "Hello World" code. I have 2 files for that.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld';

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloWorld />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**HelloWorld.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 
class HelloWorld extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="helloContainer">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
export default HelloWorld;
```

I read every post about this problem, none of them works.
I also read that it's usually problem with reactstrap, but I don't have it installed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show us your `./src/index.js` file code since that is where the error is saying the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compiler is telling you that you're not exporting anything from `App.js`, and that this is an error within your `index.js` (which you haven't shown code for, but that's where you would typically call `ReactDOM.render`).

Your `App.js` should look more like your `HelloWorld.js` (an exported component), and you should be calling `ReactDOM.render` inside of `index.js`. This is the only time you'll call `ReactDOM.render`.

#### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

#### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <HelloWorld />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

#### HelloWorld.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class HelloWorld extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="helloContainer">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HelloWorld;
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename the `App.js` file to `index.js` and delete any other index files.